# Problem in deploying library because of deletion of GeneratedBarFiles folder from IBM Integration Bus workspace

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I accidentally deleted GeneratedBarFiles folder from IIB workspace. Now i am trying to deploy a library and getting this error.

**The following Java exception occurs:

java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at com.ibm.etools.mft.broker.runtime.model.BrokerRuntimeManager.getGenBarFile(BrokerRuntimeManager.java:553)

at com.ibm.etools.mft.broker.runtime.model.BrokerRuntimeManager.deployAppOrLib(BrokerRuntimeManager.java:1814)

at com.ibm.etools.mft.broker.runtime.model.BrokerRuntimeManager.deployAppOrLib(BrokerRuntimeManager.java:1810)

at com.ibm.etools.mft.broker.runtime.wizards.steps.DeployStep.run(DeployStep.java:90)

at com.ibm.etools.mft.broker.runtime.wizards.steps.Step.execute(Step.java:48)

at com.ibm.etools.mft.broker.runtime.wizards.steps.StepEngine.runStep(StepEngine.java:106)

at com.ibm.etools.mft.broker.runtime.wizards.steps.StepEngine.run(StepEngine.java:70)
```

**

and one more error

**The following Eclipse exception occurs:

The project description file (.project) for 'GeneratedBarFiles' is missing.  This file contains important information about the project.  The project will not function properly until this file is restored.**

Is there any way to restore the .project file OR any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Try Menu: Project/Build for mqsipackagebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new workspace in another directory and it worked. It generated a new **GeneratedBarFiles** folder with a new **.project** file.